# AWS Query Can't save to a mutableList

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, kotlin, aws-amplify

I'm trying out AWS with Android Studio using Kotlin.

For the life of me, I cannot understand why my query is not saving into a local mutableList. When I output my list inside the while loop, everything is saved correctly, but once I leave the query, my mutableList becomes empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Code

```
var userContent : MutableList<MutableList<String>> = arrayListOf()
    Amplify.DataStore.query(UserInfo::class.java,
        Where.matches(UserInfo.USER.eq("$myID")),
        {
            posts ->
            while(posts.hasNext()){
                val post = posts.next()
                userContent.add(mutableListOf(post.content, post.username, post.password))
                Log.i("Testing1","$userContent")
            }
        },
        {Log.e("Auth","Error",it)}
    )
    Log.i("Testing2","$userContent")
```

Comment: Can you share these log outputs? Is "Testing2" getting printed before "Testing1"?

Comment: Testing2 is being printed before Testing1. How would I change that?

Comment: You are printing "Testing 1" inside a callback that is invoked when the query completes. Your `Datastore.query` function returns immediately and prints "Testing 2". Then when the query succeeds the lambda is invoked which adds data to the mutable list and prints "Testing 1".

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help. I'll either try to add a function after the while loop or attempt to use a coroutine. Not sure if those are the best ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Amplify - which is fine. However, as an Android Developer, you have another option now. You can use the brand NEW [AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html).

This SDK is built for use with Android Studio. Using this SDK, you can build Native Android Apps that can invoke AWS services like Amazon DynamoDB.

Here is an AWS tutorial that walks you through creating an Android app that invokes Amazon DynamoDB and SNS.

[Creating your first Native Android application using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/cross_SubmitDataApp_kotlin_topic.html)

Comment: Interesting! I'll check that out. It seems super useful

Comment: Its still early - but it works very well - esp in Android Studio.

Comment: Both links don't work.

Comment: Both links are updated to point to the AWS SDK for Kotlin Dev Guide.